# Is it possible to reconstruct $\zeta$-function knowing its zeroes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello, 
Is it possible to reconstruct the Riemann zeta function given the precise location of its infinitely many zeroes?
Thanks

Comment: Should "knowing" be replaced with "given" or "so that one knows"? $\:$ In either case, I suspect your question is off topic, although I'll wait until people who know more about the zeta function chime in before I vote to close this. $\;\;$

Comment: I don’t understand the question. The Riemann zeta function is a well-defined unique object, so it is possible to construct it even *without* knowing any additional information about its zeros.

Comment: In more general terms: given {\it any} meromorphic function over the entire complex plane. Assume it has infinitely many zeroes. Can we reconstruct the function knowing the locus of all its zeroes?


Comment: The question is badly phrased. I infer that you are asking whether there is a unique meromorphic function with a prescribed set of zeroes. That is obviously not true, since $x$ and $x^2$ have the same zeroes. Of course also $x$ and $\frac{x}{1-x}$ have the same zeroes. I suggest the following question: "Does there exists unique meromorphic function with prescribed poles (with degrees) and zeroes (with multiplicities)?"  (And I suspect the answer to be negative.)

Comment: The answer below is what I sought for $\zeta$. For the general case, note that $f$ must have infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: You should probably have a look at the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Comment: It seems clear that the intended question was "If $f$ is a meromorphic function whose zeroes coincide with those of the $\zeta$ function, must $f=\zeta$ up to multiplication by a unit?"  The example of $x$ and $x^2$ seems quite off topic.

Comment: @Steven Landsburg: 'unit' in which structure? 

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic functions on a simply connected domain $U$ with the same zeros and poles (having the same multiplicities and orders), then $f/g = e^h$ for some function $h$ analytic on $U$.  Conversely, you can multiply any meromorphic function on $U$ by $e^h$ and it will have the same zeros and poles.  

Comment: It might be useless to say but for the record and in less cryptic form: I strongly disagree that the x and x^2 examples are off topic. They as well as the other example and remarks in robot's comment are IMO very much to the point. As also later documented by Robert Israel's comment. They show with simple examples the phenomenon that obviously also applies for the zeta function or any meromorphic function that zeros without multiplicty and zeros without poles so to say cannot possibly yield that much control.  

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is well known (Riemann could have writen it)

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi^{s/2}}{(s-1)\Gamma(1+s/2)}\prod_{\Im\rho > 0}\Bigl\{
\Bigl(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac{s}{\overline{\rho}}\Bigr)\Bigr\}$$

Here $\rho$ runs through the non trivial zeros with positive imaginary part.

It is this what you call reconstruct?

Comment: Hadamard's refinement of Weierstrass factorization is relevant here: if/when we know the order of growth of zeta, and its zeros, we know it up to an exponentiated polynomial (as in R. Israel's comment), _and_ we have a sharp constraint on the degree of that polynomial. The functional equation of zeta and Stirling for the Gamma function (and Phragmen-Lindelof) give the requisite estimate to know that zeta is of order 1 in the growth sense.